# How to efficiently merge two overlapping contours into one big contour?

Tags: opencv

I have a huge image ( about 63000 x 63000 pixels = 3969 Megapixels )
what i have done so far is i decided to make "tiles" of  (1024 x 1024) and do my calculations based on these tiles, resulting in an 62 x 62 image tile grid!
(this works out very well and has the advantage of making the image viewable with zoom-in and zoom out, only viewn tiles are downsized for example)
But what i need now are the contours from the huge image!

- i use the OpenCV function "findContours" to detect contours on each
  one of the tiles.
- i have added some overlap in the tiles so i get
  overlapping contours ( 1 pixel overlap )
- i used the offset parameter
  of "findContours" to shift the contours to the right position
  into the "virtual total image"

Here are some screenshot's i made from a demo application
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I want is this:
[image]

Now my questions:

1. is it possible to stitch the contours, my worst case is a contour which covers the total image... is there some library that can do this?
2. is there a library which works on a compressed version of the total image ( like rle for example )
3. is there a way to make opencv findcontours work on 1 bit binary images ?

Here's the code used by findcontours:

```
    // Surf2DTiledData ...a gobject based class used for 2d tile management and viewing.. 
Surf2DTiledData* td = (Surf2DTiledData*)in_td;

int nr_hor_tiles = surf2_d_tiled_data_get_nr_hor_tiles(td);
int nr_ver_tiles = surf2_d_tiled_data_get_nr_ver_tiles(td);
int tile_size_x = surf2_d_tiled_data_get_tile_width(td);
int tile_size_y = surf2_d_tiled_data_get_tile_height(td);

contouring_data_obj = surf2_d_tiled_data_get_ContouringData(td);
p_contours = contouring_data_obj->p_contours;
p_border_contours = contouring_data_obj->p_border_contours;

g_return_if_fail(p_border_contours != NULL);
g_return_if_fail(p_contours != NULL);


for (y = 0; y < nr_ver_tiles; y++){
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < nr_hor_tiles; x++){
        int idx = x + y*nr_hor_tiles;
        CvMemStorage *mem = contouring_data_obj->contour_storage[idx];
        CvMat _src;
        CvSeq *contours = NULL;
        uchar* dataBuffer = (uchar*)p_data[x][y];

        // the idea is to have some extra space available for the overlap
        // detection of contours!
        // the extra space is needed for the algorithm to check for
        // overlaps of contours later on!
#define VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND 2
        int virtual_x = x * tile_size_x - VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND;
        int virtual_y = y * tile_size_y - VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND;

        int virtual_width = tile_size_x + VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND * 2;
        int virtual_height = tile_size_y + VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND * 2;
        int x_off = -VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND;
        int y_off = -VIRT_BORDER_EXTEND;
        if (virtual_x < 0) {
            virtual_width += virtual_x;
            virtual_x = 0;
            x_off = 0;
        }

        if (virtual_y < 0) {
            virtual_height += virtual_y;
            virtual_y = 0;
            y_off = 0;
        }

        if ((virtual_x + virtual_width) > (nr_hor_tiles*tile_size_x)) {
            virtual_width = nr_hor_tiles*tile_size_x - virtual_x;
        }

        if ((virtual_y + virtual_height) > (nr_ver_tiles*tile_size_y)) {
            virtual_height = nr_ver_tiles*tile_size_y - virtual_y;
        }

        CvMat* _roi_mat = get_roi_mat(td,
                           virtual_x, virtual_y,
                           virtual_width, virtual_height);

        // Use either this:
        //mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

        if (_roi_mat){
            // CV_LINK_RUNS => different algorithm!!!!
            int tile_off_x = tile_size_x * x;
            int tile_off_y = tile_size_y * y;

            CvPoint contour_shift = cvPoint(x_off + tile_off_x, y_off + tile_off_y);

            int n = cvFindContours(_roi_mat, mem, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, contour_shift);

            cvReleaseMat(&_roi_mat);

            p_contours[x][y] = contours;
        }

        //cvReleaseMemStorage(&mem);
    }
}
```

later i used opengl to make textures out of the tiles and for every tile there is a quad !
the opencv contours are not drawn as this could be too slow for now, but i draw their bounding boxes... which are drawn in opengl too..

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem, but it is hard to tell exactly what you want. Could you include the (minimal) code you're currently using, or post examples of the overlapping "tiles". They don't have to be your actual images, they just have to be able to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I will try out to modify the opencv source of CV_LINK_RUNS  which is easy enough to understand for me -> from what i can see i just have to replace the data pointer per row , this should save a lot of memory as i only need one row to be in memory !